# Can you identify this model of a twin-engine propeller aircraft?

Tags: aircraft-identification

Can anyone tell me what this is please?

[image: model aircraft]

Answer (score 2):

It resembles I.AE. 24 and I.AE. 30, but not close enough for a match.

I believe this is a model of the [De Havilland Mosquito](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Havilland_Mosquito).

[image]
Image source: [ThoughtCo.](https://www.thoughtco.com/havilland-mosquito-aircraft-2361527)

Answer (score 2):

It's not a true scale model of any real aircraft; it looks like a cross between a Mosquito and a Westland Whirlwind.

Comment: yeah, it's a toy taking inspiration from several real aircraft, and those two are the most obvious ones

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a De Havilland Hornet, though as user44163 says it's hardly a good model.
Clues for me include the colour (suggests a high-altitude aircraft) and the relatively small canopy.  But the model is not representative, so it's impossible to ID properly IMO.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Havilland_Hornet